# Which cherries do I use for cherry pie

Tags: baking

When making a cherry pie is it best to use frozen cherries or canned cherry pie filling when you don't have access to fresh cherries.

Comment: There is a third option... canned cherries.  These are canned in water rather than in sugar syrup. The Oregon brand [here](https://www.amazon.com/Oregon-Fruit-Pitted-Cherries-14-5-Ounce/dp/B000I6625I) is pretty easy to find in the US, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The frozen ones are just like fresh, only softer and they drip their juice out - but that's OK when you are going to bake them anyway. Canned cherry pie filling is sweetened and spiced, so it is going to taste the way the canner made it, not like homemade. If I go to the trouble of baking a pie, I always go all the way and make my own filling, not using the premade stuff - then I could just go out and buy the whole pie.

Answer (score -1):

It is always best to use frozen fruits. Thaw them in the refrigerator, then allow them to come to room temperature before using them so that your pastry bakes properly

I worked as a contractor at a canning plant. I had heard it is better to use frozen than canned or even "fresh" fruit. The reason is, canned fruit gets added ingredients to preserve the color...peaches look yellow, apples are white, etc. Fresh fruit has to go from the farm, to the packager, to the distributor, to the grocer...all the while, continuing to age, and sometimes sprayed with something to preserve "freshness". Frozen gets shipped from the farm, to the packager, where the fruit is frozen and kept at that state until you buy it and use it.

The only real fresh fruits are the ones that are bought at farmers' roadside markets, but then, you don't know whether any pesticides still exist on them.

Personally, I found a roadside market that has proven to be fresh and clean, and reliable. When the fruit I want is out of season, or not grown locally, I buy frozen, except bananas, which I buy at the store by the bunch, and peaches, which I buy canned, because I like the syrup.

Comment: The question was not about fresh vs. frozen fruit, but about frozen *fruit* vs. pre-made *filling*. You might want to [edit] your post.

Comment: The question is, Is it better to use frozen or canned pie filling when fresh is not available. I answered the question, with additional information explaining why frozen is better than either canned or "fresh", with the caveat of personal experience that genuine fresh is best.

Comment: Quote from the question: *"frozen cherries or canned cherry pie filling"*. While your answer gives lots of correct points, the core question remains unanswered.